# Question put on hold as primarily opinion-based when it specifically asks for not opinion-based answers

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I've written a question asking for verifiable differences between two ways of writing a `for` loop. One minute after I asked it it got put on hold "as primarily opinion-based." While I don't use the word "verifiable" in my question, I specifically ask for attributes that can be verified, and ask answerers to exclude personal preferences from their answers.

Why is my question considered opinion-based? Should I add a line like "Please do not answer solely based on opinion" when Stack Overflow rules already say that?

Text from the question:

> What are the differences or tradeoffs between using an incrementing and decrementing index in a for loop? Is there any advantage in readability, performance or something else? Is there any compelling reason (other than personal preference) for using one over the other?

Link to the question itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772077/incrementing-vs-decrementing-index-in-for-loop

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't good with open-ended "Describe all the ways in which X is Y" type questions. It's really designed for questions that have more defined answers.

Comment: looking at your question history, the majority of your recent questions are all the same pattern in asking **too-broad**, **opinion based** questions that are all **recommendations** questions as well.You have a couple of valid on topic questions, but the majority of your questions are low quality that apathy on the part of the community [have allowed to slip through the moderation cracks.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269443/should-we-treat-questions-asking-for-idiomatic-versions-of-code-snippets-as-prim?rq=1). Be aware that complaining about stuff like this brings the meta-effect.

Comment: While these are comments, they illustrate perfectly why the question invites opinionated speculative answers. http://i.stack.imgur.com/KF8r8.png

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @JarrodRoberson I'm sorry if this question came off as me complaining. I only meant to understand why my question fell into that category

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the best TV show of all time?  By the way, your answer shouldn't be opinion based, it should be verifiably correct.

Just because you state that the answer shouldn't be opinion based doesn't mean that it isn't opinion based.  If the question itself can only be answered with an opinion, then the question is opinion based, regardless of your qualification.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this applies to my question. I don't ask for the best way. I ask for any standard that can be referenced, for performance, or any other attribute. Furthermore, your own example question can indeed be answered in a non-opinion-based way (at least not based on personal opinion): the best TV show of all time is the one that has won the most awards. We can argue whether the correctness of the answer is actually verifiable, but you do have ways to compare TV shows. You also have ways to compare performance of blocks of code.

Comment: @Blueriver But your question *is* opinion based.  You don't constrict the metrics for comparison, leaving it up to the *opinions* of the reader.  You also list strictly opinion based metrics such as "readability" as examples.  If the question asks, "what TV show has won the most awards" then that is a question that would have a verifiably correct answer, but that's not what it asks.  In *your opinion* the best TV show of all time may be the one with the best awards, but I'm sure a *great* many people would disagree with you over that.

Comment: When I ask about readability, I assume people are not going to answer based on their own opinion, but rather based on some general opinion, some study, etc. I do agree with you on the TV show example, which is why I don't ask for the best way to write a `for` loop. If the question asked "what are the differences between X and Y shows?" one answer could be "X has won x awards and Y has won y awards." While awards are actually opinion-based, does that make the question opinion-based? If so, can the question be worded differently to avoid being opinion-based?

Comment: @Blueriver "I assume people are not going to answer based on [...] some general **opinion**" An opinion you say. "[...] some study" You honestly expect there to be studies on this?  And even if there were, they're not going to be studying "what's readable" as that's not an objective things they can measure; they're going to be studying aspects that can be objectively measured.  "what are the differences between X and Y shows?" Such a question is *way* too broad, as would also be the case in your situation if you made the analogous change.

Comment: As a general rule, trying to change an opinion based question into a "what's the difference" question virtually always results in a question that is Too Broad.  You could ask about a *specific* difference, or the different with respect to a very specific aspect of the two things (note again that certain qualities would themselves be too broad to exhaustively compare without constraint, such as "performance").

Comment: I see. Thank you. Since I can't list any attributes that I can prove are non-opinion-based, would you recommend I just delete the question? And as a side-note, how should I have asked this question here? I see it got some negative votes

Comment: *I ask for any standard that can be referenced, for performance, or any other attribute.* - then it is **off-topic: recommendations** - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: @Blueriver I think you asked this question the right way. The downvotes aren't there because the downvoters think this is a low quality/unclear/too broad/etc. question but because they disagree with you (i.e they believe [the question you referred to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772077/incrementing-vs-decrementing-index-in-for-loop) should stay closed) - in other words, voting is different on meta [as mentioned by the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @dorukayhan oh, I see. Thank you. Guess I should get out of SO more often.