# Question closed as asking for external resource while it isn't

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

This question of mine,

https://stackoverflow.com/q/45112318/1593077

was closed as "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" - which it is not doing; it's about doing something programmatically. Plus, it's a variant of this question,

*[How to download a file from a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652417/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-server)*

which was not only not-closed, but it has a decent number of upvotes too. Also, people downvoted the question in what seems like a kind of punishment for there possibly not being a way to do this, or for the question meriting a close.

Am I mis-perceiving the situation?

Comment: This is a typical "gimme teh codez" question and got closed for that. If it was closed as requesting off-site stuff or as "too broad" doesn't matter that much. And you should compare your question with a 6 years old one, which was asked when SO had different rulez.

Comment: This might just be a pet peeve of mine, but when a question begins with "I want..." it seems like 9 times out of 10 it's off-topic (as it almost guarantees they haven't included an attempt to solve the issue). To address why as a 3rd party: I don't feel like you've shown enough code to write a specific solution, and the comments are all about external libraries. So while you may not have intended it to be a question about libraries, that's what it appears to have turned into.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: You do realize you can prepend essentially any question with "I want" before the motivation...

Comment: @Tom: 1. So was the other, similar question. 2. Questions about idiomatic ways to do things are inherently "give me teh codez" 3. If it's a 2-3-liner, I think "gimme teh codez" should be fine. but...

Comment: @Tom: The last part of your comment sounds like a good answer. Perhaps you could make it one?

Comment: Your question is very borderline as far as asking for libraries and such. But it is very much *not* borderline as to how opinion-based it is. "Succinct" and "legible" are in the eyes of the beholder.

Comment: @NicolBolas: They're only in the eye of the beholder in terms of degree; and this was not phrased as programming golf question, nor did I indicate I wanted to trick people and then say "hah, not succinct enough". Finally, it's not as though there could be an opinion war about the legibility of code to download from a URL. And I specifically did not say "elegant" or "minimal".

Comment: @einpoklum They could, but it seems to me the majority do not. There are [excellent counter examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely), but they do show what they've tried. I tend to see much better question that start with "I'm trying..." but YMMV.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*nor did I indicate I wanted to trick people and then say "hah, not succinct enough".*" That's not why we don't want opinion-based questions. The point of the ban is that there is the number of answers with all of them being *equally* valid.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*Questions about idiomatic ways to do things are inherently "give me teh codez"*" Which is probably why we [shouldn't have an "idiomatic" tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344859/734069). Also, see [this question about idiomatic questions in general.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269443/734069)

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't have been closed using the find/recommend close reason but re-opening a question just to close it with the correct reason isn't a thing that happens.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you that it's not exactly a request for off-site resources, although the way that it was phrased made it sound like you were looking for a library that did those things.

With that said, I tend to agree with @Tom's comment and probably would've voted to close for being too broad.

Some of the adjectives ("safe, succinct, and legible") are arguably a little too subjective, but I wouldn't have VTC for that reason.

Comment: Isn't it much less broad than the other question I linked to?

Comment: Yes; Both questions are broad.